# How to send IDoc status to SAP server?

Tags: java, idoc, sapjco3

There is an outbound document on SAP server having number "3710513" and some IDoc status "X".

Using Java I want to change this document status to a different value, for example "12".

I managed to [find](https://answers.sap.com/questions/6743008/purpose-of-synch-and-aleaud.html) that common approach to send acknowledgements (and change IDoc status as well) is using `ALEAUD` message.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
    var XML = """
                <ALEAUD01>
                  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
                     <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
                         <MESTYP>ALEAUD</MESTYP>
                         <IDOCTYP>ALEAUD01</IDOCTYP>
                         <SNDPOR>MY_SNDPOR</SNDPOR>
                         <SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
                         <SNDPRN>MY_SNDPRN</SNDPRN>
                     </EDI_DC40>
                     <E1ADHDR SEGMENT="1">
                       <E1STATE SEGMENT="1">
                         <DOCNUM>3710513</DOCNUM>
                         <STATUS>12</STATUS>
                       </E1STATE>
                     </E1ADHDR>
                   </IDOC>
                 </ALEAUD01>
                """;

    JCoDestination destination = getDestinationFromMyCurrentSAPConnecton();
    IDocRepository iDocRepository = JCoIDoc.getIDocRepository(destination);
    IDocFactory iDocFactory = JCoIDoc.getIDocFactory();

    String tid = destination.createTID();
 
    IDocXMLProcessor processor = iDocFactory.getIDocXMLProcessor();
    IDocDocumentList iDocList = processor.parse(iDocRepository, XML);

    JCoIDoc.send(iDocList, IDocFactory.IDOC_VERSION_DEFAULT, destination, tid);


    destination.confirmTID(tid);
```

This sending completes without errors.

But on the SAP server in dialogue "Status Monitor for ALE Messages" I see that the target IDoc has two status columns (see scereenshot 1) (first="39", second="12"), and in the history ("Status records") there is only status "39" (see screenshot 2), which was not intended.

**Please help me to find out what is the correct way to send a status of IDoc to SAP server, so this status naturally applied to the "Status record" history.**

---

***Screenshot 1:***
[image: see screenshot]

***Screenshot 2:***
[image: see screenshot]